# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i run Marionette driver for FF 47.0.1

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

I'm using Marionette driver for first time, when i run test browser window opens and it hits URL specified in test(code) but it does not enters any text in text field and throws following error.??

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/internal/HasIdentity
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter.newRemoteWebElement(JsonToWebElementConverter.java:77)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter.apply(JsonToWebElementConverter.java:57)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:653)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:492)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:415)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.findElement(Unknown Source)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:184)
>         at com.pearson.itautomation.bca.Browser$WaitForElementFunction.apply(Browser.java:64)
>         at com.pearson.itautomation.bca.Browser$WaitForElementFunction.apply(Browser.java:48)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
>         at com.pearson.itautomation.bca.Browser.getElementWithWait(Browser.java:307)
>         at com.pearson.itautomation.bca.interaction.SendTextToElementAction.perform(SendTextToElementAction.java:64)
>         at com.pearson.itautomation.bca.BrowserAction.performWithStates(BrowserAction.java:104)
>         at com.pearson.itautomation.bca.BrowserAction.performWithStates(BrowserAction.java:80)
>         at pearson.ePortfolio.Actions.CommonActions.edTPALogin(CommonActions.java:181)
>         at TestCases_PSP.SendTaskLevelFeedbackRequest.TaskFeedbackRequest(SendTaskLevelFeedbackRequest.java:64)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.internal.HasIdentity
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         ... 60 more

FF browser Version:47.0.1
        selenium-java :2.52.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think upgrading your selenium-API explicitly in your POM file will get you off from these error and it did in my case..
    
        org.seleniumhq.selenium
        selenium-java
        2.53.0
    
    
        org.seleniumhq.selenium
        selenium-api
        2.53.0

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your selenium-java to 2.53.1. Firefox 47.0.1 already fixed the issue for selenium webdriver. You can successfully run test automation for FirefoxDriver();

Comment: upgrading to selenium java to 2.53.1 doesn't helps too..
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException

Comment: Did you use FirefoxDriver() instead of MarionetteDriver? Try this: FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage;about:home","about:blank");
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url","about:blank");
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.usedOnWindows10.introURL","about:blank");
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("devtools.devedition.promo.url","");
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required",false);
   
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);